# Setting CHOWN to 0 in perl archive tar

Tags: perl, archive, tar, cpan

I'm trying to set CHOWN to 0 so that when extracted as root the files aren't chown'd to the uid saved in the archive.  This doesn't seem to work.

```
use Archive::Tar;
use Getopt::Long qw( :config pass_through );

my $tarballName = $ARGV[0];
 my $testfix = Archive::Tar->new();
  $testfix::CHOWN=0;
$testfix->read ($tarballName);

 print "CHOWN=$testfix::CHOWN \n";

$testfix->extract()
```

The code above prints CHOWN=0, yet when I add print "CHOWN=$CHOWN \n"; to archive::tar.pm and run it I get :

```
CHOWN=0 
CHOWN in tar.pm=1
```

Is this the correct way to change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `$Archive::Tar::CHOWN`, not `$testfix::CHOWN`. Moreover, you declare `$testfix` as an object, but later use it as a prefix - these two concepts are quite different!

Comment: I had been trying Archive::Tar::CHOWN but not with the $ in front :-(, that made all the difference

Comment: @AntóinÓg: You cannot use a variable name without a sigil. You probably should re-read all the basic documentation of Perl to better understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

No.  `$testfix::CHOWN` is the `$CHOWN` variable in the `testfix` package, which isn't consulted by anything except your `print` statement.

```
$Archive::Tar::CHOWN = 0;
```

Comment: This answer is also correct, both came in at the same time. So I accepted the oldest